# Refactoring AndroidX library classes in Xamarin Android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am able to install all libraries successfully but still it is using old support library. 
How to perform auto-refactor after installing all the AndroidX library from Nuget?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What tutorial are you following for the migration? Did you take a look at this? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/androidx-nuget-packages-are-stable/

Comment: I used this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx to Migrate AndroidX.

Comment: I am using Mac. Visual studio 8.5+ and Xamarin.Android 10.2+.

Comment: Step which I followed. 1) Updated Xamarin Framework to 9.0. 2) Added all required packages of AndroidX from Nuget.

Comment: when clicking on "Migrate to AndroidX" option. Its loading the visual studio but none of namespaces is refactoring to AndroidX.

Comment: Did you follow these instructions “If your application includes any dependencies that have not been migrated to the AndroidX namespace, you'll have to use the Android Support Library to AndroidX Migration package“. There’s several things you can still do as mentioned in that article that you shared with me